# How do I assign a name to a value in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

How do I assign a value to a name?
For example If the word "WHOLE" is in Column I it will count as "1", and if the word "HALF" is in column I that it will count as ".05"?

Comment: Did you mean you want to transform text to its value in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Create a cross reference table and use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

To do the sum in the column we can do use SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,I2:I6))
```

[image]

Comment: Okay so my VLOOKUP would be on another sheet to create the V look up? Then the formula would be =VLOOKUP(L10,A:B,2,FALSE)?

Comment: If the table is on a different sheet you need to include the sheet name in the reference.